# Pause And Reverse An Animation on iOS/OS X

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation, quartz-core

I'm trying to make an cancelable interactive transition on iOS by taking the advantage of CAMediaTiming Protocol. I have successfully implemented pausing and resuming a UIView animation. But still failing on implementing pausing and reversing a UIView animation. Here is my code:

Reverse the paused animation:

```
let layer = navigationController.transitionView.layer // the layer where animation takes place
let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
layer.speed = -1.0
layer.timeOffset = 0
let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime() ,fromLayer:nil) - (transitionDuration() - pausedTime)
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
```